# Kivy Mapview - Cannot load a integrated map

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently trying to display a map in kivy using the garden.mapview module.

This is my code so far:

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from mapview import *

class WeatherRoot(ScreenManager, BoxLayout):
    pass


class RegisterPage(Screen, BoxLayout):
    pass


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

class Map(MapView):
    try:
        mapview = MapView(zoom=1, lat=67, lon=42, cache_dir="cache")
    except:
        print(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WeatherApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
WeatherRoot:
<WeatherRoot>:
    RegisterPage:

<RegisterPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        padding: [100, 50, 100, 50]
        Map:
            id: map
            zoom: 2
            lat: 67
            lon: 42
        TextInput:
            font_size: 30
```

When running this code, the following shows up on the screen:

[image: The screen]

Then I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='a.tile.openstreetmap.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2/3/1.png (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AE5C370D68>, 'Connection to a.tile.openstreetmap.org timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))
```

I am new to the mapview module and I have not been able to find any answers on the internet.

How could I fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is a firewall or proxy enabled enabled in the place you use them?

Comment: @eyllanesc It seems like that was the case but now I am getting the following error: Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image.

Comment: Have you installed SDL2 ? What is your OS ?